# How to know if an Indian Star Tortoise has laid eggs

Tags: breeding, turtles

I have a pair of male and female Indian Star Tortoises (Geochelone elegans).

As far as I can tell, they have mated successfully. However, I have also observed that my female tortoise was digging in the ground, which can indicate she was preparing to lay eggs. How can I confirm whether or not she has laid any eggs?